# Where to add validation with JQuery-UI AJAX PHP?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-validate

I have tried all variances I can think of to add validation after the form DOM object is created.  The code itself works as far as opening and closing the jquery-ui.dialog.  I just can't figure out where to splice in the handler for any validation.

```
 //party_device_edit Begin 
    var party_device_edit = $('#party_device_edit').dialog({
      autoOpen: false,  width:'auto',  modal: true, title: 'Edit Device', 
      buttons: {
        'Save': function(){
**//Tried Adding Validation Here**
            $.ajax({
            url: '/party_device/save.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $('#party_device_edit_form').serialize(),
            success: function(data){
              //Re-queries the data and refreshes the piece of the page that has updated data.
              $.get('helper.php?function=party_device&id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>',function(data){$('#party_device').html(data);});
              $('#party_device_edit').dialog('close');
            }
          });
        return false;
        }
      }
    });
    $(document).on('click', '.party_device_edit', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
          party_device_edit.html(data);
**//Tried Adding Validation Here**
          party_device_edit.dialog('open');
**//Tried Adding Validation Here**
        }
      });
    });
    //party_device_edit End
```

Comment: It would be helpful for you to also show your relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You put the `ajax` inside the `submitHandler` in the Validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), and then assign a `.submit()` to the "Save" button for your modal.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#party_device_edit_form").validate({
        // // validate rules & options,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/party_device/save.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    //Re-queries the data and refreshes the piece of the page that has updated data.
                    $.get('helper.php?function=party_device&id=<?php echo $_GET['
                    id '];?>', function (data) {
                        $('#party_device').html(data);
                    });
                    $('#party_device_edit').dialog('close');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });

    var party_device_edit = $('#party_device_edit').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 'auto',
        modal: true,
        title: 'Edit Device',
        buttons: {
            'Save': function () {
                $("#party_device_edit_form").submit();
            }
        }
    });

});
```

I cannot create a specific demo since you failed to show your HTML, but here is a test case that is *very* similar to yours...

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/7bA8M/**

Comment: I appreciate your example.  I have tried to implement your example from here and what you have in jsfiddle.  However I am now stuck on how to get the submitted form to post to the ajax call and not to the url.  I think I am missing a .preventDefault somewhere.  The HTML for the form is dynamically created via the jquery-ui.dailog.

Comment: @MattSmith, yeah, that's your problem.  The HTML of the form **must** exist when `.validate()` is called.  So simply move your entire `.validate()` function into the same place that creates your form's HTML.  Place it immediately _after_ the code that creates the HTML.

Comment: Sparky fixed the primary piece I was having trouble with, thank you.  The final working code is above.